# Angular call service after or in timeout

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have this function that gets the innerHTML from an element. It works but only in a setTimeout function:

```
firstFunction() {

    let _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if(_this.myPanel != undefined){
        this.pathText = _this.myPanel.nativeElement.innerHTML;
        console.log(this.pathText);
      }

    }, 500); //THIS IS OK, console shows correct results after 0.5s

    this.changePathText(this.pathText); //CALL FUNCTION THAT CALLS SERVIS
}
```

This get's the innerHTML well and shows good data in the console after 0.5s. Now I want to get that data in a service, so after the timeout I call the `changePathText` function that has the service:

```
  changePathText(pathText) {
    console.log("changePathText in map activated", pathText);
    this.sightService.changePathText(pathText);
  }
```

**The problem is here is that this servis is only called at the beginning of the first function, not after the timeout.** So the service is never called with the new data.

I tried calling the service directly in the firstFunction after the `console.log(this.pathText)`, but I get an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'changePathText' of undefined`

How can I achieve this ?

This is what the service looks like:

```
  changePathText(pathText){
    console.log("servis changePathText activated", pathText);
    this.pathTextSource.next(pathText);
  }
```

And yes, I imported the service in the first file. It only doesn't work when I call the service in the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out ! 
The problem was with **this**. Because it was a nested this, I had to use _this in the timeout.

```
let _this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(_this.myPanel);
  if(_this.myPanel != undefined){
    let ivan = _this.myPanel;
    console.log("Seg ivan myPath", ivan);
    //console.log("Seg myPath", JSON.stringify(this.myPanel.nativeElement.innerHTML));
    console.log(_this.myPanel.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    this.pathText = _this.myPanel.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    _this.sightService.changePathText(this.pathText);
  }

}, 500);
```

Comment: you can also skip the this designation by using an arrow function:

setTimeout(() => {
 // use this. here
});

Comment: IkePr, thank you for all your hard work on solving this problem. I spent several hours on it until I found this post. Thank you!